# Chropath is not visible/working in Salesforce

Tags: xpath, salesforce, chropath

The ChroPath extension in Chrome browser is not visible for Salesforce website where as it is working in other sites.

**Chrome browser version:** 83.0.4103.61

**ChroPath version:** 6.1.4

*ChroPath in other sites - The ChroPath tab is visible*

[image]

*ChroPath in Salesforce: The ChroPath tab is not visible*

[image]

It is working in the Salesforce VisualForce page but not on the Salesforce Aura components, Salesforce Lightning Web Components pages.

The extension is enabled and even it was working properly earlier in the Salesforce site. I have tried re-installing the extension and browser but it is not working in Salesforce website.

Comment: Did you test it with Firefox ? What happens if you disable your other addons ? I guess you could submit your issue on the repo : https://github.com/Autonomiq/ChroPathFeedback, per email (chropath[at]autonomiq.io) or via chat (chropath_slack_channel).

Comment: Great E.Wiest Even if I disable other addons the result is same. Xpath helper is working fine in this same scenario. I have already sent this infomration to the above mentioned email address and slack channel. The concerned person is looking into the issue right now. For clear tracking I will post in GitHub too